# How remove the white space between my menu and slider?

Tags: css

This is my site http://185.105.4.132/~orangeye/

When I scroll down, a white space appears between my menu bar and slider.

how do I remove that?

This is what I have done to place the logo at the very top. After doing this, the white space started appearing.

```
.edgtf-page-header {
   margin-top: 30px; 
   padding-top:290px;
   background-image: url('http://185.105.4.132/~orangeye/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/home-logo.png');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center top; 
   position: relative;  
   display: block;  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe if you take a look at class="carousel-inner skrollable skrollable-between" and use some js to do it as position:absolute and top:0px

Comment: Moved to chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35026/discussion-on-answer-by-silenced-how-remove-the-white-space-between-my-menu-and

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your .edgtf-page-header class is currently styled as:

```
{
    margin-top: 200px;
    /* padding-top: 290px; */
    background-image: url('http://185.105.4.132/~orangeye/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/home-logo.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
```

The margin-top is what is causing the whitespace. Setting this to 0px will fix the issue.

Comment: thanks for replying back. Actually, I have re-introduced the padding-top so as to place my logo up there. 

I want to remove this white space. http://uploadpie.com/aKl2Q
 Just to make sure we are talking about the same thing. thanks again.